# Populate data from 2 related collections with Meteorjs and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, aggregation-framework, database

I'm struggling a bit with how to retrieve data from 2 related tables with MeteorJs.

I have 2 collections (From SimpleSchema)

```
users : {
  _id : hdhdgehehehehe,
  firstname: John,
  branch: dhdhdhdhdhdhdhd
}
```

And a second collection

```
branches : {
  {
    _id : dhdhdhdhdhdhdhd,
    description: admin
  },
  {
    _id : eebdbbbdbdbdbdb,
    description: management
  }
}
```

On the server/publication
I want to have list all users with the branch description as well, 
something like :

```
users : {
  _id : hdhdgehehehehe,
  firstname: John,
  branches : {
    _id : dhdhdhdhdhdhdhd,
    description: admin
  }
}
```

Help please... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can publish fields from multiple collections by returning the cursor in an array. Here's an example:

```
Meteor.publish('user.branches.info', function() {
    //if no user is logged in stop the publication
    if(!this.userId) this.stop();

    //save the branch id as a variable
    const branchId = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).branch;

    //return an array holding the user data and the branch data
    return [
        Meteor.users.find(
            { _id: this.userId }, 
            { fields: { firstname: 1, branch: 1 }
        ),
        Branches.find(
            { _id: branchId }, 
            { fields: { description: 1 }
        );
    ]
});
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for answer, I have done this before :

```
        const users = User.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
 const ids = users.map(function(t) { return t.profile.branch });
 const branches = Branch.find({_id: {$in: ids}});

 console.log(branches);

 return [
  users,
  branches
 ] 
```

But i dont know to get those data from the client